# How do I show that the polynomial $f(x) = x^2 + x + 3$ $∈$ $Z_7[x]$ is a primitive polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

I understand that a primitive polynomial is a polynomial that generates all elements of an extension field from a base field. However I am not sure how to apply this definition to answer my question. Can someone explain to me how I need to start please?

Comment: Your definition of a primitive polynomial isn't clear. The polynomial itself can't generate anything.

Comment: Please see my solution to the following http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827068/primitive-root-in-quotient-ring/827127#827127

Comment: Even if by that polynomial you *actually* meant its image in some quotient ring (field), which one did you mean? A quadratic extension of $\;\Bbb F_7\;$ ?

Answer (score 3):

A primitive polynomial root is also the minimal polynomial of a `primitive root of unity` in $\mathbf F_7$. Let $\xi$ be a root of $f$. The field $\mathbf F_7(\xi)$  is the field $\mathbf F_{49}$ and its nonzero elements form a group of order $48$.
It suffices to show $xi$ has order $48$. Anyway its order can only be a divisor of $48$, i.e. $1,2,4,8,16, 3,6,12,24,48$.

Let's compute the powers of $\xi$ from its minimal polynomial. I give the details only for one of them: from $\xi^2=-\xi-3$, we deduce $$\xi^4 =(\xi+3)^2=\xi^2+6\xi+2=5\xi-1$$. Similarly
\begin{alignat*}{4}
\xi^8&=3,&\qquad&\xi^{16}=2, &\qquad&\xi^{24}=-1,&\qquad&\xi^{48}=1.
\end{alignat*}
The order cannot be $3, 6$ or $12$, since otherwise we would have $\xi^{24}=1$.

Thus $\xi$  is a primitive root of unity in $\mathbf F_{49}$, which proves $f$ is a primitive polynomial in $\mathbf F_7[x]$.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to be vulgar, you can simply evaluate the expression at all 7 integer values, and show none of them is $0(7)$

Alternatively, $(x+4)^2 + 1\equiv x^2 + x + 3(7)$ and $-1$ is not a quadratic residue of $7$

Comment: This proves the polynomial is irreducible, but doesn't prove that a root must be a generator of the multiplicative group $F_{49}^{*}$.

Answer (score 0):

The polyomial is irreducible for the reasons given in Will Brooks' answer. $F_{49}^{*}$ is cyclic of order 48. You want to check that a root $\alpha$ of the polynomial must have order 48. Since every element of $F_{49}^{*}$ has order dividing $48$, it's enough to check that $\alpha^{16} \ne 1$ and $\alpha^{24} \ne 1$. So it's enough to check that your given polynomial doesn't divide $X^{24} - 1$ or $X^{16} - 1$. You can do that by computing powers of $X$ modulo $f(X)$. (Successively compute $X^2$, $X^4$, $X^8$, $X^{16}$ and $X^{24}$ modulo $f(X)$.)

Comment: Could you explain what $F^∗_49$ is? Also could you elaborate on why it is enough to check that $α^16≠1$ and $α^24≠1$ please?

Comment: $F_{49}$ is the field with $49$ elements and $F_{49}^{*} = F_{49} - \{0\}$. The other thing is because any number dividing $48$ which isn't equal to $48$ must divide one of the numbers $16$ or $24$. If $\alpha$ has order dividing $16$, then we must have $\alpha^{16} = 1$, and similarly for $24$.

Comment: Ok, are 16 and 24 known as maximal proper factors of 48? Also was there a formula for obtaining the numbers 16 and 24?

Comment: The only prime numbers dividing $48$ are $2$ and $3$. So if $48 = ab$ and $b > 1$, $b$ must be must be divisible by $2$ or $3$. Therefore $a$ must divide $16$ or $24$.